# What does error `TooManyTopics` mean?

Tags: ink

While trying out my contract I get the error: [`TooManyTopics`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/72dd574acf805fda1dc1e64b7bbd510e12a81312/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L817-L818), what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have [max. 4](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/crates/env/src/types.rs#L189) [`#[ink(topic)]`](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/topic) in an `#[ink(event)]` when using the `DefaultEnvironment`. The signature of the event, however, is by default one of the topics of the event so that leaves 3. Except if you annotate the event with `#[ink(anonymous)]` ([ref](https://use.ink/basics/events)).

Comment: How is the signature of the event encoded? I suspect it is in Topic[0]?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/how-to-identify-received-contract-event/8376#8376